# What is $f^{-1}(f(x)^2)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

For real $x>1$, the function $f(x)$ is increasing and maps the interval $(1,+\infty)$ onto $(-\infty,+\infty)$, so that we may define inverse function  $f^{\text{-1}}:\mathbb R \to (1,+\infty)$  by

$$  f^{\text{-1}} (f(x))=x$$

is it possible to determine
$$  f^{\text{-1}} (f(x)^2) ?$$

Comment: Is $f(x)^2$ meant to be $[f(x)]^2$ or $(f\circ f)(x)$?

Comment: @mrtaurho $f(x)^2$

Comment: What do you mean by "determine"? If you know formulas for $f, f^{-1}$ you can write down a formula for $f^{-1}(f(x)^2)$.

Comment: @PatrickDanzi Well, you missed the point of clarifying to which you refer :) Anyway, from your response I suppose you mean $[f(x)]^2$, i.e. the square, and not composition of $f$ with itself.

Comment: I don't know that there is much more to say unless you have a more specific family of $f$ for which this expression can be simplified.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ can’t be found in terms of standard mathematical function even if $f$ is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to simplify the expression $f^{-1}(f(x)^2)$ without more specific information about $f$.

For example, maybe $f(x)=\ln(x-1)$, which meets your conditions. Then $f^{-1}(f(x)^2)=e^{\ln(x-1)^2}+1=(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)}+1$. Is there some way to write that in terms of "$f(x)$" and $f^{-1}(x)$" that is simpler than $f^{-1}(f(x)^2)$?

For another example, maybe $f(x)=\frac{x^2-2x}{x-1}$, which meets your conditions. Then $f^{-1}(f(x)^2)=1+\frac12\left(\frac{x^2-2x}{x-1}\right)^2+\frac12\sqrt{4+\left(\frac{x^2-2x}{x-1}\right)^4}$. Is there some way to write that in terms of "$f(x)$" and $f^{-1}(x)$" that is simpler than $f^{-1}(f(x)^2)$? Consistent with the previous example?

Comment: Dose it help to know that $f$ is the logarithmic integral $li(x)$?

Comment: @PatrickDanzi Probably, although I do not know enough about that function or its inverse to offer a simplification.